# do css media queries work on sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, css

having trouble getting this to work and I thought I would ask if this is even supported in SharePoint 2010(or is it a problem in my css)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes CSS media queries work...I have implemented a responsive layout for both 2010 and 2013, however quite difficult in 2010 but media queries will work as this is related more the browser rather than the platform.

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: yeah it certainly helps...i just have to fix my own stuff but at least I know that. thanks! appreciated